# Is it possible to do clustering?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

Is it possible to do clustering where DMGR having appsrv profile with 2 different nodes residing on 2 different physical machines where EACH node has 2 servers in there respective node machines.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a deployment manager can manage many nodes and nodes can have multiple profiles/servers.

Comment: how we can do clustering and what type of cluster is that?Because the scenario is like this dmgr-> node1-> server1 and server2(same machine) and node2->server3 and server 4(another machine).so now all these have to be under one cluster .how? is this vertical or horizontal?

Comment: You could consider it both vertical and horizontal, the distinction is not really so important when you're talking so few servers.  You're asking about the basic topology of Network Deployment, you really should read the Concepts and Planning guide for your WAS ND release.

Comment: thanx @conver i was bit confused in using the terminology whether we can call  it is combination of vertical and horizontal.now got clarity thank you,